# Python print or sum unexpected behavior

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, shell

My script is filling the file called "numbers 1.txt" by sequence from 1 to 10.

Then the script calculate and print out the sum of all numbers from the file.

When I've tried to execute this script:

```
def FillNumbersFile(numbers_file_name, numbers):
    with open(numbers_file_name, 'w') as numbers_file:
        for index in range(1, numbers + 1):
            numbers_file.write('%d\n' % index)

def PrintFileNumbersSum(numbers_file_name):
    # define an empty list
    numbers = []

    # open file and read the content in a list
    with open(numbers_file_name, 'r') as numbers_file:
        for line in numbers_file:
            # remove linebreak which is the last character of the string
            current_number = int(line[:-1])

            # add item to the list
            numbers.append(current_number)

    print(sum(numbers))


numbers_file_name = "numbers1.txt"
number_count = 10

FillNumbersFile(numbers_file_name, number_count)
PrintFileNumbersSum(numbers_file_name)
```

I've got output:

On Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

```
55nger
```

On Windows 10

```
55
```

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: If windows produces the correct result then it can't be a problem with your code. Is this repeatable every time on ubuntu or did you type in some characters whilst waiting for the result?

Comment: Might be because of the `'\n'`... The newline character is a  bit different between Windoes and Linux...

Comment: you do not need to remove the newline character. it's working for me if i just use current_number = int(line) on line 14, also if i use the same code, it's still working

Comment: @Tomerikoo Python uses universal newlines, so ``\n`` is not necessarily a *literal* ``\n`` but "environment dependent newline" (including ``\r\n``, ``\r``, ...) as needed. ``print`` to ``sys.stdout`` certainly does use universal newlines.

Comment: Is there any *other* code producing output, either as part of this script or calling this script? ``55nger`` is the output of writing ``55`` after ``??nger\r``, e.g. ``print('??nger\r', '55', sep='')``.

Comment: @Sayse yes it's repeatable every time on Ubuntu when I do it under the Ranger by the command :shell -w python3 myScript.py. But if I repeat it under Ubuntu shell without the Ranger all works fine. So it's look like the Ranger issue.

Comment: @kvantour, my question was caused by [ranger's bug](https://github.com/ranger/ranger/issues/2135)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unexpected output of the script published in the question is the result of incorrect behavior of ranger (file manager) shell that invoked by internal command

```
:shell -w python3 myScript
```

The command

```
python3 myScript
```

under Ubuntu shell and under MS Windows 10 works fine.

[About this case was opened bug issue](https://github.com/ranger/ranger/issues/2135)